# Button that hides content doesnt work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, toggle, hide, show

I got a button and a block of content. If i press the button, the content width becomes 0px and its not visible anymore. If i press the button again it makes the content block width 100px - its visible again.

Problem - when i test this on iPhone and press Hide button - it doesn't work. It just hides the background (The text of content block is still visible).

I didn't include some special meta tags or anything like that, im not using jQuery for this - just javascript.

Code is realy simple:
click on the button to hide content block:

```
document.getElementById('content_block').style.width = '0px';
```

click again on same button to show content block:

```
document.getElementById('content_block').style.width = '100px';
```

Any suggestions?

Note - this problem only occurs on the actual iPhone, not website simulators or other phones.

Comment: Try setting 'overflow:hidden' as a style attribute on content_block?

Comment: Try adding a javascript tag to the question.